# JAVA API call Compare response with Previous response

Tags: java, json

I am trying to make api call every 60 mins which returns json response like below:

```
[{
"queryId" : uniqueID,
"state": "FINISHED | FAILED | RUNNING"
},
{
"queryId" : uniqueID,
"state": "FINISHED | FAILED | RUNNING"
},
]
```

I want to run first time and prepare each document and store and for the next api call i want to compare current response with previous response with below condition:

1: if same queryId exit in previous response and state as FINISHED | FAILED don't consider to store.

So idea is to get every 60 secs new queryID which is running in system and store it for further analysis.

Below is my sample snipeet:

```
@Override
        public void run() {
            stopRequested = false;

            while (!stopRequested)
            {
                try {
                        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","");
                        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","");

                        Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication ("", "".toCharArray());
                            }
                        });
                        URL url = new URL("");
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                        conn.connect();
                        int responsecode = conn.getResponseCode();
                        if (responsecode != 200) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponseCode: " + responsecode);
                        }

                        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
                            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                            String responseLine = null;
                            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                response.append(responseLine.trim());
                            }

                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.toString());
                            System.out.println(array.length());

                            JSONArray presResponse = array;

                            for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Query
                                String queryId = object.getString("queryId");
                                String state = object.getString("state");

                                if (checkQryExit(queryId, state, presResponse)) {
                                    String strResponse = String.format // metric return in json
                                            ("{\"queryId\":\"%s\"," + "\"state\":\"%s\"}", queryId, state);
                                    System.out.println(strResponse);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    conn.disconnect();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: OK, so store the results somewhere. - in memory, file, database?

Comment: probably file ..i had trouble in compare current response with previous response  not in storing part.